# I want to add some additional data in name field (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

i have create a duplicate row using replicate here is my function

```
public function copy($id){

    $task = Task::find($id);
    $copy = $task->replicate();
    $copy->save();
    session()->flash('msg','successfully Copied!');
}
```

*i want that on copy my name field should changed as*

**Task 1 - copy**

if i make 2nd copy it should be as

**Task 1 - copy 2**

Please help me to make it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$task = Task::find($id);

$copy = $task->replicate();
$copy->name = $copy->name.'2';
$copy->save();
```

Comment: its replacing name with copy 2 i also need name 
mean now how can i concatenate name with copy word @jaimin

Comment: @recoverymen i have changed my answer. do you want something like this?

Comment: very close
i am using this now 
$copy->name = $copy->name." ".'Copy/'.$id;
if i make copy for copyid its create new copy as copyid Copy/29 because its id is 29 and if i again make copy for copyid it should be Copy/30 but now its making Copy/29 @jaimin

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$task = Task::find($id);

$copy = $task->replicate();

// If the name contains the word 'copy' create the next one
if (str_is('copy', $copy->name)){

    //Get the last word
    $words = explode(' ', $copy->name);
    $last_word = array_pop($words);

    // If the last word is 'copy' create the right number, else it's the first copy
    if ($last_word == 'copy'){
        $copy->name = str_finish($copy->name, ' 2');
    } else {
        $number = strval(intval($last_word) + 1);
        $copy->name = str_finish(implode(" ", $words), ' ' . $number);
    }
// Else create the first one
} else {
    $copy->name = str_finish($copy->name, ' - copy');
}

$copy->save();
```